# R Conditionally Merge Rows

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a very large database (with thousands of questions) from a forum where people answer questions and their answers are accepted or not. If someone answers more than once I need to combine their answers and put them at the first time they answered.  Here is a made up example of what I'm dealing with

[image]

Here is the dataframe

```
        df1 <- data.frame(
          questionID = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2),
          userID = c(101, 101, 101, 102, 102,103,102),
          accepted=c(0,0,1,0,0,1,0),
          answer=c('text1','text2','text3','text4','text5','text6','text7'),
          time=c('12:00','12:30',"1:00","1:30","2:00","2:30","3:00"))
```

Since userID (101) answered question ID (1) 3 times, and the third answer was accepted, I need to concatenate the answers and put this at the earliest time (which is 12:00). The same thing for userID(102) who answered twice and neither was accepted. The result would be like this (with the output dataframe):

[image]

```
     out <- data.frame(
        questionID = c(1,1,2,2),
        userID = c(101, 102, 102,103),
        accepted=c(1,0,0,1),
        answer=c('text1+text2+text3','text4','text5+text7','text6'),
        time=c('12:00',"1:30","2:00","2:30"))
```

I've seen some solutions for problems like this but none appear to address this precise situation. Is there some way to do this in R?

Comment: You’re right. I changed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could `summarise` by `paste`ing the 'answer' into a single string, while getting the `last` of 'accepted' and `first` 'time' value after doing a group by

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>% 
    group_by(questionID, userID) %>%
    summarise(accepted = last(accepted), 
              answer = str_c(answer, collapse="+"), 
              time = first(time))
# A tibble: 4 x 5
# Groups:   questionID [2]
#  questionID userID accepted answer            time 
#       <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>             <fct>
#1          1    101        1 text1+text2+text3 12:00
#2          1    102        0 text4             1:30 
#3          2    102        0 text5+text7       2:00 
#4          2    103        1 text6             2:30
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, .(accepted = last(accepted), 
   answer = paste(answer, collapse= "+"), time = first(time), .(questionID, userID)]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think any answer can be accepted (not only the last one), so using `data.table`, we can do

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df1)[,.(accepted = +any(accepted == 1),answer = paste(answer, collapse = "+"),
          time = first(time)), .(questionID, userID)]

#   questionID userID accepted            answer  time
#1:          1    101        1 text1+text2+text3 12:00
#2:          1    102        0             text4  1:30
#3:          2    102        0       text5+text7  2:00
#4:          2    103        1             text6  2:30
```